# Test Centos performance

Tags: centos, benchmark

I have a VPS with 4GB Ram and Core17 processor. The server its working really bad, the basic commands like w, ls or top have a serious delay and the page speed from google webmaster is way up. Of course, the tech team say that everything its fine, but i am pretty sure they oversell.

Is there a performance test which i can run in order to show them that the server is really slow?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, there is a special test suite for Linux called [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/).

It has almost every possible benchmark you can think off available and you can easily export everything to a nice html page with graphs.

If you are not happy with their services, I suggest you just change hosting provider.

Comment: Phone them up and threaten to leave before actually leaving.  Often, they'll offer a discount or an upgrade just to keep your business.